# SpringFox: Array of Enum Displays as Array of String

Tags: java, swagger-2.0, springfox

We are using the springfox swagger library (testing both 2.7.x and 2.9.x) in our Spring Boot rest project. I have an ApiModel that returns fields using two enums. One is a single enum value while the other is an array. For example:

```
@ApiModel("MyResponse")
public class MyResponseDTO {

    FirstEnum firstData; //Containing options "ONE", "TWO", "THREE"

    List<SecondEnum> secondDataList; //Containing options "DO", "RE", "MI"
}
```

The resulting swagger yaml shows firstData with the correct values, but secondDataList as a generic array of strings:

```
firstData (string, optional) = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE']
secondDataList (Array[string], optional),
```

I Tried experimenting with the `@ApiModelProperty` annotaion but to no avail. Is there a way to get the secondDataList entry to show the allowable values?

Comment: do u have a solution now? i run into the same problem.